# view using Where sum, group by

Tags: mysql

I have two tables daily_orders & payments. Have created a view with daily_orders (item price + shipping) final order value against the payment received. Join is at order item id

Now facing challenge to get the Amazon easy ship charges for a order item id. As it is charged on a order id level

How to achieve the below calculation in view ?

Amazon Easy Ship Charges per order item id should be sum of Amazon Easy Ship Charges & Amazon Easy Ship Charges Tax  for a order id / count of order item id present in the order. count is available in the daily_orders table

please look at the image of the view attached red numbers are supposed to be calculated but it is showing as 0?

**SQL daily_orders TABLE CREATE WITH SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amazon1`.`daily_orders` 
(`order-id` varchar(19), `order-item-id` bigint(14), `sku` varchar(11), `quantity-purchased` int(1), `currency` varchar(3), `item-price` int(3), `shipping-price` int(3), `Order_Count` int(1), `Tally_SKU` varchar(13), `Bill_no` varchar(9)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). 
INSERT INTO `amazon1`.`daily_orders` 
(`order-id`, `order-item-id`, `sku`, `quantity-purchased`, `currency`, `item-price`, `shipping-price`, `Order_Count`, `Tally_SKU`, `Bill_no`) 
VALUES ('171-5459791-9380334', 28373004618851, 'HP3001B-23', 1, 'INR', 150, 50, 2, 'HP30001-Black', 'A15-87693'),
('171-5459791-9380334', 62282678063643, 'HW30003-B13', 1, 'INR', 150, 50, 2, 'HW30003-Black', 'A15-87693'),
('403-6411573-8057942', 25067932242499, 'HP3001B-46', 3, 'INR', 450, 150, 1, 'HP30001-Black', 'A15-87694');
```

**SQL payments TABLE CREATE WITH SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amazon1`.`PAYMENTS` 
 (`order-id` varchar(19), `order-item-id` bigint(14), `sku` varchar(11), `quantity-purchased` int(1), `currency` varchar(3), `item-price` int(3), `shipping-price` int(3), `Order_Count` int(1), `Tally_SKU` varchar(13), `Bill_no` varchar(9))
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). INSERT INTO `amazon1`.`payments` (`order-id`, `order-item-id`, `sku`, `quantity-purchased`, `currency`, `item-price`, `shipping-price`, `Order_Count`, `Tally_SKU`, `Bill_no`) 
 VALUES ('171-5459791-9380334', 28373004618851, 'HP3001B-23', 1, 'INR', 150, 50, 2, 'HP30001-Black', 'A15-87693'), 
 ('171-5459791-9380334', 62282678063643, 'HW30003-B13', 1, 'INR', 150, 50, 2, 'HW30003-Black', 'A15-87693'), 
 ('403-6411573-8057942', 25067932242499, 'HP3001B-46', 3, 'INR', 450, 150, 1, 'HP30001-Black', 'A15-87694');
```

**SQL view**

```
 CREATE or replace VIEW `recon` AS select 
`daily_orders`.`order-item-id` AS `order-item-id`,
`daily_orders`.`quantity-purchased` AS `quantity-purchased`,
`payments`.`order-item-code` AS `order-item-code`,

 SUM(CASE WHEN `payments`.`amount-description` = "Amazon Easy Ship Charges" or `payments`.`amount-description`="Amazon Easy Ship Charges Tax" THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS `easy_charges`,

(`daily_orders`.`item-price` + `daily_orders`.`shipping-price`) AS `final_value`,
sum(`payments`.`amount`)  AS `final_rcvd`,`daily_orders`.`Tally_SKU` as `tally_sku`
from (`daily_orders` join `payments` on((`payments`.`order-item-code` = `daily_orders`.`order-item-id`))) 


group by `payments`.`order-item-code`,`daily_orders`.`order-item-id`,`daily_orders`.`quantity-purchased`
```

Images:

[image: payments TABLE]

[image: daiy_order table and view required]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have formatted the question. Please read the question above. Thanks